# Login for DDP API in Chimp tests (Meteor)

Tags: meteor, authentication, cucumber, webdriver-io, ddp

I'm using Chimp to test my DDP API. As such, using the `server` object. What's a good way to do login?

Spying the DDP messages teaches me login looks like this:

```
{
  "msg": "method",
  "method": "login",
  "params": [{
    "user": {
      "username": "myname"
    },
    "password": {
      "digest": "f0e4c2f76c58916ec258f246851bea091d14d4247a2fc3e18694461b1816e13b",
      "algorithm": "sha-256"
    }
  }],
  "id":"1"
}
```

I could try to write my own logic to do this login, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
function login(data) {
  return Meteor.call('login', {
    user: { username: data.username },
    password: {
      digest: Package.sha.SHA256(data.password),
      algorithm: 'sha-256'
    }
  });
}

server.execute(login, { username: username, password: password });
```

To prevent disconnection problems, at the end of the test I do:

```
server.call('logout');
```